# Reusing numerical node ids in reseting gephi application

Tags: java, for-loop, gephi

Im making an application that takes node/edges inputs then processes them through Gephi, then print out a json data of that graph. After I use the application, i want to clear out all previous data and put in new data. The issue is that to print out the graph data, i have to use a for loop and the bounds are being problematic.

My application:

If I for example have 2 graphs the both with 500 nodes. I enter the first. I loop through the numerical id's

```
for(int x =0; x< g.NodeCount(); x++)
{
   g.getNode(x).NodeData().allThDataINeed;
   // g is a DirectedGraph object

}
```

and that works fine.The numerical id's are from 0-499 as it should be. Then I delete all those nodes and add the 500 new ones. and run the new loop.

My Issue:
The nodeCount is still equal to 500 but the node ids run from 500-999. Which means my loop does not work. Now when i use this loop, the nodes it's referencing are null so the data is null. I also do this with edges, and it has the same problems, but if i fix the nodes the same solution will fix the edges.

What i Need:
I need a way to reset the numerical id's. Basically, after nodes 0-499 are deleted, the next 500 node should fill those spots, having the numerical id of 0-499 rather than 500-999.

other codey bits:
to clear my graph i use the code

```
g.clear();
```

after i end my application i set all variables within the class that does these processes to null, including g, my graph. Then just to be safe, set that encompassing class to null, then reinitialize it when i want to use it again. Still those node id's are not being refilled.

Comment: What type is the object g?

Comment: directedGraph, sorry i edited the post